# mysql query - how do I need to split the table data

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, triggers

Thanks in advance.

I have a table, called person_details. Here's the sample dat of person_details table.

```
ID    Name_and_Dept         Location
-------------------------------------
1     John Doe - Finance    New York
2     Emmy Joe - IT         Boston
3     Stella Job - Admin    Chicago
4     Steve Doe - Finance   Los Angeles
5     Frank Chad - Sales    Boston
6     Rich Moss - Admin     New York
```

I have two new tables called person_dept and person_location. I need the person_details table data in both person_dept and person_location tables in following way.

**person_dept** table

```
P_ID  Name          Dept
---------------------------
1     John Doe      Finance
2     Emmy Joe      IT
3     Stella Job    Admin
4     Steve Doe     Finance
5     Frank Chad    Sales
6     Rich Moss     Admin
```

person_location table

```
L_ID  Name          Location
---------------------------
1     John Doe      New York
2     Emmy Joe      Boston
3     Stella Job    Chicago
4     Steve Doe     Los Angeles
5     Frank Chad    Boston
6     Rich Moss     New York
```

Not sure if I can achieve this using a query or stored proc or a trigger. I really appreciate if someone could please help. Thanks, again.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for [SUBSTRING_INDEX](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) function. If you want your tables strutcured as in your question, you could use two INSERT queries like these ones instead of a trigger:

```
INSERT INTO person_dept
SELECT
  ID,
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(Name_and_Dept, ' - ', 1),
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(Name_and_Dept, ' - ', -1)
FROM person_details;

INSERT INTO person_location
SELECT
  ID,
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(Name_and_Dept, ' - ', 1),
  Location
FROM person_details;
```

Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5cc17/1). If you need the record to be automatically into person_dept and person_location table, you need a trigger, and you could start with something like this:

```
DELIMITER |
CREATE TRIGGER populate_tables AFTER
INSERT ON person_details
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO person_dept VALUES
    (new.ID,
     SUBSTRING_INDEX(new.Name_and_Dept, ' - ', 1),
     SUBSTRING_INDEX(new.Name_and_Dept, ' - ', -1)
     );
  INSERT INTO person_location
  VALUES
    (new.ID,
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(new.Name_and_Dept, ' - ', 1),
    new.Location
    );
END;
|
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
When new records are added to person_details table, I want the records to be automatically populated in to person_dept and person_location table. I think we need a trigger to do this. What do you think?

Comment: @ram yes you need a trigger for this, please see my updated answer. I'm not able to create a fiddle, but it will work on mysql. Also, I'm only considering inserting new rows, if you need to updated exising ones i can update my answer

Comment: Thank you, fthiella,I really appreciate your help.